# Can't log in to keycloak admin console after setting up email

Tags: smtp, keycloak

I am working with Keycloak, version 19.0.3.
I am using it in docker container, using image

```
quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0
```

I am using postgresql database.
I am hosting it on azure.
I had a working setup with a few clients, scopes etc. Everything worked fine. Then I tried to set up email provider to be able to receive email confirmations. I successfully received test email and I clicked save. Then after a while my session refreshed and I no longer can log in to the administrator console. I get the following error log:

```
2022-11-14T09:46:17.033164754Z: [INFO]  2022-11-14 09:46:17,030 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-191) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=[realm_id], clientId=security-admin-console, userId=null, ipAddress=[ipAddress], error=user_not_found, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, redirect_uri=[redirect_uri], code_id=[code_id], username=[username], authSessionParentId=[authSessionParentId], authSessionTabId=[authSessionTabId]
```

During startup the following message shows up:

```
Failed to add user '[admin_user]' to realm 'master': user with username exists
```

However this user is nowhere in the database.

The administrator log in credentials are set up using environmental variables and the whole setup is still in dev mode.

This is not the first time it happened. It happened once before however I did not connect it to the fact that setting up email account might have caused it. I thought it was because I accidentally upgraded keycloak to version 20, so I started from the beginning.
This time I set up email and came back after 20 minutes. My username and password are invalid. I have them saved in autocomplete, so its not because I wrote my credentials wrong. Nothing else changed.
I thought that maybe its because I have my realm set up to use email as username, so I tested with email address I just added, stil nothing.
I struggled with it for a long time. I am at my wits end. Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue. Not sure whether it was caused by SMTP setup.

I have checked the databases from the back-up and the new one (after day of work that also included SMTP setup).

The `admin` `user_entity` in the database was updated to my email address somehow with keeping the user id. So with my email address and original `admin` password I am able to sign into the master console.

I hope it'll help.

PS. I recall now that during first 'Test connection' for SMTP execution Keycloak asked me to type an email address for testing (where the test email is going to be sent). Now I think it is at that moment the `admin` username was changed to my personal email.

Comment: That was it. For some reason login changed to this test email. Thank you